# Android AlarmService repeating alarm repeats once more after cancel is called

Tags: android

First off,this site is great and everyone is so helpfull.  This is my first post so forgive me if i have ommited anything.

I create an alarm like so:

```
private void startLocation() {

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyWeatherUpdateService.class);
    PendingIntent service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (60 * 1000),
            Long.parseLong(prefs.getString("listpref", "60000")), service);

}
```

In this method which is called inside a fragment, context is from getApplication (), listpref is a string update interval in milliseconds.

I cancel it by:

```
public void endLocation() {

    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyWeatherUpdateService.class);
    PendingIntent service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarm.cancel(service);

}
```

Ensuring that the intent/pending intent is the same.

Now i have 2 issues:

1) the alarm fires almost imediately after creation, even though i tell it to start after 1min.
2) when i call cancel, the alarm fires once more before the alarm is cancelled.

With question 1) why does the alarm fire so soon? And with 2) is this working as intended or should the alarm cancel immediately like i want it to.

If i have not supplied enough info, ill add more code if required.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> the alarm fires almost imediately after creation, even though i tell it to start after 1min

That is because you are using `RTC` with an `elapsedRealtime()` starting time. Those need to match. The simplest solution is to switch to `ELAPSED_REALTIME`.

> when i call cancel, the alarm fires once more before the alarm is cancelled.

Try replacing `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` with `0`, at least in the `PendingIntent` for your `cancel()` call.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer however, i sorted it myself. I was actually calling the startlocation method twice. Sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare  thanks!!, defintely upvote for this fine answer